# Creating a specific regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex in Code::Blocks to find all occurrences of when a function is called with a specific parameter.

The function is called:

```
int mdw_button(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int bn, ....
```

and I want to find occurrences of when the 5th parameter is a specific value...

So basically

- start with `mdw_button(`
- then skip past 4 occurrences of numbers or letters ended with a comma
- then match on the fifth..

OK I have been asked for a minimum working example:

- In Code::Blocks open the 'Find in Files' dialog with CTRL-SHIFT-F
- Check 'Look in all project files'
- Check 'Regular Expression'
- In the "Text to search for" field I have tried:

  `mdw_button(.*15`

Gets a lot of results...basically anything that starts with:
`mdw_button(`
and has a 15 anywhere later on the line. This works but has a lot of false positives.

`mdw_button(.*[,]+ 15`
This works and I get a shorter list, but still lots of false positives

So many things I have tried give me absolutely no results at all:

`mdw_button(.*[,]+ 15`

`mdw_button( ([A-Za-z0-9]{1}[,])4 15`

I want something that will match the pattern of:
[any text or number followed by a comma]

Then I want to skip past 4 of those and match whatever is next

here is some examples of code I am looking through:

```
mdw_button(xa, ya, xb, ya+bts-2, 26, num, type, obt, 0,  15,  13, 14, 1,0,0,d); ya+=bts; // stat | fall | carry
mdw_button(xa, ya, xb, ya+bts-2, 49, num, type, obt, 0, 12 ,  15,  0, 1,0,0,d); ya+=bts; // door type
mdw_button(xa, ya, xb, ya+bts-2, 4,  num, type, obt, 0, abc, atc,  0, 1,0,0,d); ya+=bts; // set linked item
mdw_button(xa, ya, xb, ya+bts-2, 50, num, type, obt, 0, abc, atc,  0, 1,0,0,d); ya+=bts; // enter mode (up | down)
mdw_button(xa, ya, xb, ya+bts-2, 53, num, type, obt, 0, abc, atc,  0, 1,0,0,d); ya+=bts; // move type
mdw_button(xa, ya, xb, ya+bts-2, 51, num, type, obt, 0, abc, atc,  0, 1,0,0,d); ya+=bts; // exit link show
mdw_button(xa, ya, xb, ya+bts-2, 52, num, type, obt, 0,  13,  15,  0, 1,0,0,d); ya+=bts; // get new shape
mdw_colsel(xa, ya, xb, ya+bts-2, 5,  num, type, obt, 0,   0,   0,  0, 0,0,0,d); ya+=bts; // change color
```

Comment: I suggest you go to https://regex101.com/, create a few test cases, and create a regex as best you can. Then come back here and edit your question to include both the examples you were using and the regex you attempted which didn't work. A question like that will be easy for others to answer, and the experience will leave you better able to understand the answer.

Comment: Please provide a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this:

```regex
mdw_button\((?:\s*[\w+-]+,){4}\s*50,
```

The specific fifth parameters value is "50" in this example. It will match only the part up to and including that fifth parameter.If you want to match the whole call, you should add a `.*?;`. It will still just match the call and not the whole line.

You were starting off correctly. but:

- to match a literal `(` you have to escape it as `\(`
- if you want to count the first four parameters, you should group them with a non-capturing group like this: `(?:\s*[\w+-]+,)`
- this group starts with an optional amount of whitespace: `\s*`, followed by minimum 1 or more word characters (`\w`) or `+` or `-` - to support more operations or spaces in the parameters, you will have to extend this!
- inside the group also the final `,` is important
- you want to occur the group exactly 4 times: `{4}`
- again an optional amount of whitespace is following
- then the parameter you search for is following
- end with a comma to prevent that the results only match the start of the parameter you look for.

Please keep in mind that you can't build a full expression parser with regex, so if you have parenthesis or more complex expressions as parameters, you probably are better off with a regular parser.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. Unfortunately when I tried it in Code::Blocks I got no results.  Your very informative answer has given me some clues to how I might go about figuring it out on my own though. Anyway I have manually searched through my code and found all the occurrences I needed. Thank you again for all the time and effort you took to explain this to me.

Comment: I just tried it in the given IDE now and to succeed with my solution, you will have to set the option "Use Advanced RegEx searches". You will find it in the settings menu: Settings > Editor... > section General settings > tab "Other editor settings" - if you don't set this it seems that Code::Blocks does not get any regex grouping with (), don't know what regex implementation that is.

Answer (score 0):

Not a regex, but a way to filter your data using `awk`.

Lets say your input data is in file data.txt.

You could do:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ", " } /^mdw_button/ { if ($5 == "4") print }' data.txt
```

- `BEGIN { FS = ", " }`: set the field separator to `,` and
- `/^mdw_button/`: line starts with "mdw_button"
- if the 5th field == "4", print that line.

With your example data, the result is:

```
mdw_button(xa, ya, xb, ya+bts-2, 4,  num, type, obt, 0, abc, atc,  0, 1,0,0,d); ya+=bts; // set linked item
```